# Making div element dynamic with another function

Tags: jquery

I have a block of code that I want to try and refactor.

```
    $(function () {
        $('.dots:nth-of-type(1)').click(function () {
            currentSlide(1);
        });
        $('.dots:nth-of-type(2)').click(function () {
            currentSlide(2);
        });
    });
```

How can I make the nth-of-type(1) dynamic along with the currentSlide(1) so that for each nth-of-type(), I just need to click on it in order currentSlide to be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery's `index` [method](https://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
$(function() {
    $('.dots').click(function() {
        currentSlide($(this).index());
    });
});
```